Fast filling cells in Power BI
So, I have a table with a date column, and I want to quickly fill it up to and including 2025. And manually it is too inefficient.

In Excel, this can be done simply - select 2 cells and, pulling at the lower right corner, stretch to the desired row.
Is it possible to do something similar in Power BI?
P.S. The "Edit Query" window is open.

Consult google on how to create a calendar table. Your question shows absolutely no effort on your side. I vote to close it.

You can create a table first in Transformation layer with dummy data. Then go to Advance editor and replace all codes with this below codes. Just set your own start and end date in the code.
let
    // Define the start and end dates
    StartDate = #date(2023, 1, 1),
    EndDate = #date(2023, 12, 31),

    // Calculate the number of days between the start and end dates
    DayCount = Duration.Days(EndDate - StartDate) + 1,

    // Generate a list of dates
    DateList = List.Dates(StartDate, DayCount, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),

    // Convert the list to a table
    DateTable = Table.FromList(DateList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Date"}),

    // Change the column type to date
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(DateTable,{{"Date", type date}})
in
    ChangedType



create a blank query in PQ
= Query1(#date(2021, 1, 1), Number.From(#date(2025,12,31))-Number.From(#date(2021, 1, 1)), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))

click 'To Table'

transform date to start of month

remove duplicates


please see the M coding below
let
Source = Query1(#date(2021, 1, 1), Number.From(#date(2025,12,31))-Number.From(#date(2021, 1, 1)), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Calculated Start of Month" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", Date.StartOfMonth, type date}}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Calculated Start of Month")

in
#"Removed Duplicates"
